# what's the meaning of "occupying one's skin"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, symbols, paraphrasing

The excerpt is from the following lines:

> Mules and other brutes had *occupied their skins*. But now, the sun and
> the bossman were gone, so the skins felt powerful and human. They
> became lords of sounds and lesser things. They passed nations through
> their mouths. They sat in judgment.

- Source: *Their eyes were watching god*, by Zora Neal Hurston

thanks in advance

Comment: I have no earthly idea. Is there more to this source?

Comment: If you can tell us where the extract comes from we _may_ be able to help you, otherwise retread the previous part of the story and keep going and it should become clearer, though not necessarily. I have tried to read Finnegan's Wake.

Comment: It is from the novel their eyes were watching god by zora neal hurston.

Comment: @minoosalesi You should edit your OP (original post) and add this information there. I've already done it for you. The results should appear soon.

Comment: This whole passage smacks of innovative, poetic language. These are novel, singular idioms, so you're not going to find an answer on this message board. Someone will probably close this thread and refer you to the literature board: https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i didnt know such a thing exists. lol. thanks